# Netherlands acquiring 30% ruling after two months of starting the job

Tags: taxes, netherlands, salary, tax-deductions

I was accepted to work in a company in the Netherlands.

I understood that there is 30% ruling new law, which is applied to people who have a master degree and under 30 years old.

I'm 26 years old, but I will be graduated from my master program 2 months after starting working with the company.

When I get my master certificate, can I apply for the 30% ruling so I can get a better net salary ? or I'd need to wait until the next contract?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the experience of getting the 30% ruling a while after I started working - so retroactive requests are not a problem (though they might be if you cross the boundary of a tax year; not sure about that point).

However, [**edit**] a Master's degree and being under 30 merely reduce the salary minimum to apply the 30% ruling. As explained, for example, [here](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/local/official-matters/highly-skilled-migrants/thirty-percent-ruling/30-percent-ruling-indepth), the criteria are (emphasis mine):

> - You must be **an employee** of a company in the Netherlands.
> - You have specific **professional expertise** that is scarce or not available in the Netherlands. Highly skilled migrants are deemed to have such expertise when their income meets the **salary requirements**.
> - You and your employer **agree in writing** that the 30% ruling applies to your situation.
> - You have been **recruited or transferred from abroad** (and you have lived more than 150 km from the Dutch border for more than 24 months prior to working in the Netherlands.)

and as @Gala points out, the salary limit [is lower for people with a Master's who are under 30](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/living_and_working/working_in_another_country_temporarily/you_are_coming_to_work_in_the_netherlands/30_facility_for_incoming_employees/conditions_30_p_facility/you_possess_a_specific_expertise).

So it looks like what you need is some kind of agreement or confirmation from your employer that you qualify. I don't think you can apply for the 30% ruling on your own without employer involvement.

Comment: You can apply for 30% yourself